# Как отсортировать ключи словаря в зависимости от количества элементов в значении

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка

Есть словарь в котором значения представлены в виде списка.

Пример dict = `{1: [0], 2: [0, 1, 2], 3: [4, 1, 5, 5, 1], 4: [2, 3]}`

Ответ: `3, 2, 4, 1`

Нужно вывести ключи в зависимости от значения.

Подскажите как подобное реализовать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dct = {1: [0], 2: [0, 1, 2], 3: [4, 1, 5, 5, 1], 4: [2, 3]}
print(sorted(dct, key=lambda k: len(dct[k]), reverse=True))
```